# References to the same instance if objects are based on the same NodeEntity

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Say I have a simple class named Foo. Foo only has one field, a string called name.

If I have persisted an object of type Foo to the database and I have a repository that allows me to find Foo objects in the database by either name or ID, is it possible to get references to a single instance so that in the next example:

```
// The Foo node with name "bar" has id 1
Foo foo1 = fooRepository.findOne(1);
Foo foo2 = fooRepository.findByName("bar");
```

foo1 and foo2 both reference the same object?

Edit: I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 3.2.1.

Comment: Probably there is a Neo4j specific way, but another one would be an AOP that wraps around every method that returns a Foo and changes that return object to the singleton...

Comment: Totally dependent on the behavior of `fooRepository`.   Does it construct a new one each call?  Maintain a cache so it can re-return previously found instances?

Comment: In this case the `fooRepository` is an interface that extends `GraphRepository<Foo>` so that `findByName()` is a derived finder method. Both methods are derived or inherited.

Comment: I don't know how repositories are implemented internally, but I suspect it is very unlikely that foo1 and foo2 would reference the same object. They should be equal, but rather separate objects... But why do you need that kind of deep knowledge ?

Comment: @cichystefan: yes, by default foo1 and foo2 will not reference the same object: a separate object will be created to represent the same data in both cases. I suspect in this case that the user wants to make sure that a previously instanced (mayhaps heavy) object is re-used, due to performance and/or resource usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no client-side caching of entities in SDN3.

So you get a new instance.

It might be different in SDN4, not sure.

Comment: In SDN 4, they'll reference the same object. This applies only if they're both loaded within the same SDN Session.